# I am trying correct some spelling error in variable names in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have two (2) datasets, one containing the list of stores and ID and the other containing details about sales.

There are errors in the spelling of some store names in the latter.

I wrote an R code to aid in solving this issue, but I am stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

To my understanding, I need to create a dictionary of correct spellings.

Please find below some of my attempts.

```
# fix missing values in store names

# define regular expression pattern
pat <- "^.*PARVIFLORA ?OM?A.*$"
gsub(pat,   "Parviflora Łomża", sum_jan[, 1])

# using find and replace method

Replaces <- data.frame(from = c("PARVIFLORA ?OM?A", "PARVIFLORA ?WIEBODZIN"), to = c("  Parviflora 
Łomża", "Świebodzin"))

ABNewDF <- replace(data = sum_jan, Var = "sum_jan[, 1]", replaceData = Replaces,
                   from = "from", to = "to", exact = FALSE)

ABNewVector <- FindReplace(data = ABData, Var = "a", replaceData = Replaces,
                       from = "from", to = "to", vector = TRUE)



# using string

reported <- sum_jan
corrections <- rbind( c("PARVIFLORA ?WIEBODZIN", "Świebodzin"))
colnames(corrections) <- c("wrong", "right")
corrections

typos <- aregexec("PARVIFLORA ?WIEBODZIN", reported)
regmatches(reported, typos)

# dictionary of corrected misspellings
```

Comment: Without seeing your input data and your expected output, we can only guess at what the problem might be.  Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for advice on providing a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: if you had a list each of the correct spellings and the incorrect spellings it would probably easy to help you.

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65568874/3358272